# Running a vm inside a vm

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, windows-server-2008

I have a cloud VM from a commercial cloud VM company. This host VM is windows server 2008. I have installed vmware player on this host and I want to run an ubuntu vm in it. VMWare player shows an error when I try to run ubuntu - "VMWare player and hyper-v are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMWare player."

**Failed solutions:**

1 - Remove hyper-v from control panel -> remove windows features. Hyper-V was not even present here.

2 - Remove hyper-v by using powershell. It says success, but my problem was not fixed.

How do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.** Hyper-V is running on the computer that hosts your VM.

If you're using Azure, then it looks like [some classes of instances support nested virtualization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/). You may have to use Hyper-V instead of VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Windows Server 2016 or Windows 10 with at least Anniversary Update (v1607), here it is [possible to run nested VMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization) with Hyper-V.

> Nested virtualization is a feature that allows you to run Hyper-V
>   inside of a Hyper-V virtual machine. In other words, with nested
>   virtualization, a Hyper-V host itself can be virtualized. Some use
>   cases for nested virtualization would be to run a Hyper-V Container in
>   a virtualized container host, set-up a Hyper-V lab in a virtualized
>   environment, or to test multi-machine scenarios without the need for
>   individual hardware.

But the nesting only works with Hyper-V. So you can't run VMware inside a Hyper-V VM.

> Virtualization applications other than Hyper-V are not supported in
>   Hyper-V virtual machines, and are likely to fail. This includes any
>   software that requires hardware virtualization extensions.

Comment: So, if I get a windows server 2016 VM on azure or whichever service that runs on hyper-v, then I will be able to do nested virtualization (using hyper v of course) ?

Comment: try it out. I haven't tried it out myself